# Is the problem in the below code related to memory allocation for array of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

In the below code, I am trying to read an input line from STDIN using function usergetline and in the main function, I am assigning the input string to an array of char pointers. (char *lineptr[MAXCOUNTLINE])

While within the 1st while loop, the input line is stored in the lineptr (as can be seen when I print the lineptr[iplinecount]), however, once I come outside the loop, all it prints is new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* function declarations */
int usergetline(char *, int);

/* constants */
#define MAXCOUNTLINE 10
#define MAXLINECOUNTWIDTH 100
#define DEFPRINTFRLASTCOUNT 8

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ipline;
    int iplinecount,shifter;
    iplinecount=0;
    char *lineptr[MAXCOUNTLINE];
    /* continue to accept the lines till the time EOF is not encountered and 
     * max count of lines is not exceeded */
    while((iplinecount < MAXCOUNTLINE) && (usergetline(ipline,MAXLINECOUNTWIDTH) >0)){
        lineptr[iplinecount] = ipline;
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("iplinecount: %d\n",iplinecount);
        printf("ipline: %s\n",ipline);
        printf("strlen of ipline: %d\n",strlen(ipline));
        printf("*(lineptr+iplinecount): %s\n",lineptr[iplinecount]);
        printf("strlen of *(lineptr+iplinecount): %d\n",strlen(lineptr[iplinecount]));
        printf("value at ipline %p\n",ipline);
        printf("value at *(lineptr+iplinecount) %p\n",lineptr[iplinecount]);
        #endif
        iplinecount++;
    }
    printf("iplinecount = %d\n",iplinecount);
    shifter=0;   
    while(shifter < iplinecount){
        printf("strlen: %d\n",strlen(*(lineptr+shifter)));
        printf("%s\n",*(lineptr+shifter));
        shifter++;
    }
}

/* usergetline: function to accpet an input line from STDIN */
int usergetline(char *ipline, int maxlengthofip)
{
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while((maxlengthofip-1) && ((c=getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n')){
        maxlengthofip--;
        *ipline=c;
        ipline++;
        i++;
    }
    if (c=='\n'){
        *ipline='\n';
        ipline++;
        i++;
    }
    *ipline = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Suppose this file name is exercise5-13.c.
I am using cygwin environment. After compilation (with -D DEBUG flag), when I execute the program, as in. ./exercise5-13.exe
Output is:

```
testing
iplinecount: 0
ipline: testing

strlen of ipline: 8
lineptr[iplinecount]: testing

strlen of lineptr[iplinecount]: 8
value at ipline 0xffffcdf0
value at lineptr[iplinecount] 0xffffcdf0
iplinecount = 1
strlen=0
```

My limited understanding and argument against initialization of array of char pointer is that when I am assigning (line 21)

'''
lineptr[iplinecount] = ipline;
'''

then, lineptr is being assigned an address of ipline which in itself is pointing to the string constant fetched from the STDIN *testing* in this case.
I was expecting that eachnew string fetched from STDIN would be first stored in *line* pointer and from their, the address of the first element of the string would be stored in the  char pointer array. However, char pointer array is empty?

Comment: What is the question? I failed to understand.

Comment: In the second while loop, from line 35 to 38, why the printf statement (printf("%s\n",lineptr[shifter]);) doesn't print the entered string?

Comment: `ipline` is used before initialisation. Pass `&ipline` to `usergeline()` and allocate memory to `*ipline` in `usergeline()` and then write content in that memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the uninitialized pointer

```
char *ipline;

//...

usergetline(ipline,MAXLINECOUNTWIDTH)
```

within the function `usergetline` that invokes undefined behavior.

You need to allocate dynamically memory where you are going to read data and the address of the allocated memory to assign to the pointer `ipline`. So the pointer `ipline` must be passed to the function by reference that is through a pointer to the pointer.

The function declaration in this case will look for example like

```
int usergetline(char **ipline, int maxlengthofip);
```